# deeplearning4j error when building NeuralNetConfiguration config class : org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4jBackend$NoAvailableBackendException

Tags: java, maven, deeplearning4j

I am trying to start a new project in intellij to do some deep reinforcement learning with deeplearning4j but am getting errors when building the NeuralNetConfiguration class. I think the problem is with my pom.xml file.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.MultiLayerConfiguration$Builder.build(MultiLayerConfiguration.java:719)
at org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.NeuralNetConfiguration$ListBuilder.build(NeuralNetConfiguration.java:258)
at test.<clinit>(test.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4jBackend$NoAvailableBackendException: Please ensure that you have an nd4j backend on your classpath. Please see: http://nd4j.org/getstarted.html
at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.initContext(Nd4j.java:5131)
at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.<clinit>(Nd4j.java:226)
... 3 more
```

I have both of these dependencies in my pom.xml file which i thought would be enough cf. http://nd4j.org/getstarted.html ? I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to this stuff...

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>nd4j-native-platform</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use CUDA v9.2+ installed and NVIDIA-compatible hardware, add the below dependency.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>nd4j-cuda-10.1</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0-beta6</version>
</dependency>
```

if you use native implementation of ND4J as a CPU backend, add the below dependency.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>nd4j-native</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-beta6</version>
</dependency>
```

refer this [documentation](https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/deeplearning4j-config-gpu-cpu).

I hope this helps.

Comment: @mgnbar can i know, how did you fix this issue?